# How do I set the environment for a .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service?

Tags: .net-core

Here's what I tried:

1. I took at a glance at the source for [Host.CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/v3.0.0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Host.cs#L63) and started by setting the environment variable DOTNET_Environment to "Production". That failed.
2. So then I tried the classic ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. Nope.
3. Then I tried adding `hostsettings.json` to the root of the executing project:

```json
{
    "Environment": "Production"
}
```

Nada.

How in the heck do you specify a production machine in order to use the `appsettings.Production.json` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I'm dumb.

First, check your `Properties/launchSettings.json` file for the value of "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT". That's probably enough for most, including me.

It will, in fact, also look for a `hostsettings.json` file in the project root by default. It was just being overridden in my case by the `launchSettings` environment variable declaration.

However, if you want to use the JSON approach I mentioned in the question, but with something other than the default file name or location, you gotta call `ConfigureHostConfiguration` in your `IHostBuilder` chain and add the file explicitly.

Like so:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AddJsonFile("arbitraryFileName.json");
            })
        .ConfigureServices(
            (hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.Configure<Settings>(
                    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
            });
```

It does indeed default to "DOTNET_" as the prefix instead of "ASPNETCORE_", so make sure both are set on your production machine/VM/service.

Comment: Have youby chance tried to use a publish profile for this service while setting the environment eg. <EnvironmentName>Dev</EnvironmentName>  for the target ?  Ive been trying that and it doesnt seem to work, however it works as expected for a web app.

Comment: Sorry I missed this! No, I have not tried it with a publish profile for a console app. However, I would still opt to set/read an environment variable on the destination machine to indicate its region (dev, stage, prod, etc). You might also be able to execute a script specific to the destination OS on publish that sets the environment.

Comment: I'm working on a WebJob console app (dotnet 5) but nothing works for me ;-( it always says 'Production'

Comment: Just for folks coming to this later, The `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is part of a chain of environment variables that an application checks as part of startup. In a traditional web application, it would first check the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable. Now puts priority on the `DOTNET_` key prefix. So on your worker, it uses `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` by default, even if you add `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. I typically avoid this whole issue by setting a different environment variable with a unique name, and then use the extension: `await CreateHostBuilder().UseEnvironment(_Environment).Build().RunAsync();`